# Insert removed element in generic list

Tags: java, generics, collections

I want to remove remove element from the end of `ArrayList` and set it in the position `i`. I don't care about order of the elements but i want this operation to be O(1).

My code:

```
    private void removeElement(int i, List<? extends MyClass> objects) {
        if (i >= objects.size() - 1) {
            objects.remove(objects.size() - 1);
        } else {
            objects.set(i, objects.remove(objects.size() - 1));
        }
    }
```

By doing this i'm removing object at `i` index from my `ArrayList` in O(1) time complexity.

My problem is that Java won't let me set removed element in `i` position. I'm getting:

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found '? extends MyClass', required '? extends MyClass'.

I know about "producer extends consumer super" rule. I understand that `? extends MyClass` object could be different from exact `? extends MyClass` List generic type. But shouldn't it be allowed to insert back element retrieved from the same list?

Comment: It doesn't know the item has been removed from the same list. Java first evaluates all the arguments and then calls the method.

Comment: Do you really need an upper bounded wildcard list, or can you probably get rid of the ? extends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the wildcard; and I don't even think you need a bound:

```
private void <T> removeElement(int i, List<T> objects) {
```